# Laravel 5.3 - Issue with relationship array & mailable - Undefined index

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

This is on the **SallaryCrudController**:

```
public function remindsallary(Request $request)
{
    $sallary = \App\Models\Sallary::where('isPaid', 'No')->get();
    $salcount = count($sallary);
    if ($salcount > 0) {
        Mail::to($request->user())->send(new RemindSallary($sallary));
        \Alert::success('Email sent with ' . $salcount . ' reminders.')->flash();
        return redirect('admin/sallary');
    } else {
        \Alert::error('There are no open payments.')->flash();
        return redirect('admin/sallary');
    }
}
```

This is my **RemindSallary** mailable:

```
class RemindSallary extends Mailable
{
use Queueable, SerializesModels;

/**
 * The Sallary instance.
 *
 * @var Sallary
 */
public $sallary;
public $employee;

/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($sallary)
{
    //
    $this->sallary = $sallary;
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    $this->employee = \App\Models\Employee::where('id', $this->sallary['employee_id'])->first();
    return $this->view('emails.remindsallary')->subject('Payment reminder');
}
}
```

And this is my **remindsallary** view:

```
@section('content')         
@foreach ($sallary as $emp)
<p>Name: {{ $employee->name }} :: Value: {{ $emp->value }}</p>
@endforeach
```

The error I get when I try to fire it up is:

```
Undefined index: employee_id
```

**Description**:

I can print the relationship fine when I request all the data in a row. But in this case, I'm requesting all the data in all rows where 'isPaid'  = 'No'.

So, I'm sure this is wrong:

```
$this->employee = \App\Models\Employee::where('id', $this->sallary['employee_id'])->first();
```

Since it's an object I can't call it like that, but I don't know how else to call it though.I have tried sallary->employee_id to no avail. When I do that I get:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$employee_id
```

How can I fix this? I need to grab the employee name on the Employee table and pass it through the mailable.

Answer (score 1):

**Finally solved it**

The trick was calling the relationship directly instead of introducing the 'Employee' model altogether.

I only had to add this on the blade view:

```
@foreach ($sallary as $emp)
<p>Name: {{ $emp->employee['name'] }} :: Value: {{ $emp['value'] }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I can't **yet**